# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Map<String, boolean>' is not ass ignable to parameter of type 'IterableShim<[String, boolean]>'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

i have the following typescript code snippet:

```
setSelection(selection: Map<String, boolean>) {
        this.selection = new Map<String, boolean>(selection);
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'Map' is not ass
>   ignable to parameter of type 'IterableShim<[String, boolean]>'.
>     Property '"*es6-shim iterator*"' is missing in type 'Map'.

What am i doing wrong (the code is working though)?

I am using typings with the es6-shim Type descriptions (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/es6-shim).

Many thanks,

Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by calling the `"entries()"` method of the map. This provides an iterable which the Map constructor awaits.

```
setSelection(selection: Map<String, boolean>) {
    this.selection = new Map<String, boolean>(selection.entries());
}
```